# OpenCV error in codes

Tags: c++, opencv, namespaces, computer-vision, matching

I'm doing a project on opencv on image matching.
The lines

```
    std::vector<cv::Keypoint> keypoints1;
    std::vector<cv::Keypoint> keypoints2;
```

have the error: namespace "cv" has no member "Keypoint"
How do i solve this?

Another error is in the code

```
    //Define feature detector
    cv::FastFeatureDetector fastDet(80);
    //Keypoint detection
    fastDet.detect(image1, keypoints1);
    fastDet.detect(image2, keypoints2);
```

where the error says: 
object of abstract class type "cv::FastFeatureDetector" is not allowed:

function :cv::FastFeatureDetector::setThreshold" is a pure virtual function

function :cv::FastFeatureDetector::getThreshold" is a pure virtual function

function :cv::FastFeatureDetector::setNonmaxSuppression" is a pure virtual function

function :cv::FastFeatureDetector::getNonmaxSuppression" is a pure virtual function

function :cv::FastFeatureDetector::setType" is a pure virtual function

function :cv::FastFeatureDetector::getType" is a pure virtual function

Can someone please help?

Here is the whole code:

```
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"
    #include"opencv2\core.hpp"

    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    void main(int argc, const char** argv)
    {
        Mat image1 = imread("image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
        Mat image2 = imread("image2.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

        //Define keypoints vector
        std::vector<cv::Keypoint> keypoints1;
        std::vector<cv::Keypoint> keypoints2;

        //Define feature detector
        cv::FastFeatureDetector fastDet(80);
        //Keypoint detection
        fastDet.detect(image1, keypoints1);
        fastDet.detect(image2, keypoints2);

        //Define a square neighbourhood
        const int nsize(11);                            //size of the neighbourhood
        cv::Rect neighbourhood(0, 0, nsize, nsize);     //11x11
        cv::Mat patch1;
        cv::Mat patch2;

        //For all points in first image
        //find the best match in second image
        cv::Mat result;
        std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;

        //for all keypoints in image 1
        for (int i = 0; i < keypoints1.size(); i++)
        {
            //define image patch
            neighbourhood.x = keypoints1[i].pt.x - nsize / 2;
            neighbourhood.y = keypoints1[i].pt.y - nsize / 2;

            //if neighbourhood of points outside image,
            //then continue with next point
            if (neighbourhood.x < 0 || neighbourhood.y < 0 || neighbourhood.x + nsize >= image1.cols || neighbourhood.y + nsize >= image1.rows)
                continue;

            //patch in image 1
            patch1 = image1(neighbourhood);

            //reset best correlation value;
            cv::DMatch bestMatch;

            //for all keypoints in image 2
            for (int j = 0; j < keypoints2.size(); j++)
            {
                //define image patch
                neighbourhood.x = keypoints2[j].pt.x - nsize / 2;
                neighbourhood.y = keypoints2[j].pt.y - nsize / 2;


                //if neighbourhood of points outside image,
                //then continue with next point
                if (neighbourhood.x < 0 || neighbourhood.y < 0 || neighbourhood.x + nsize >= image2.cols || neighbourhood.y + nsize >= image2.rows)
                    continue;

                //patch in image 2
                patch2 = image2(neighbourhood);

                //match the 2 patches
                cv::matchTemplate(patch1, patch2, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);

                //check if it is best match
                if (result.at<float>(0, 0) < bestMatch.distance)
                {
                    bestMatch.distance = result.at<float>(0, 0);
                    bestMatch.queryIdx = i;
                    bestMatch.trainIdx = j;
                }
            }
            //add the best match
            matches.push_back(bestMatch);
        }
        //extract the 25 best matches
        std::nth_element(matches.begin(), matches.begin() + 25, matches.end());
        matches.erase(matches.begin() + 25, matches.end());

        //Draw matching results
        cv::Mat matchImage;
        cv::DrawMatchesFlags();
    }
```

Comment: 1) You are using `using namespace cv;` and `using namespace std;` why do you use **std::**, **cv::** again?

2) `function :cv::FastFeatureDetector::setThreshold" is a pure virtual function` Maybe you have to inherit abstract base class and implement all the virtual functions in it.

Comment: "Pure virtual function" means this is an abstract base class that concrete classes inherit from. You either need to implement a concrete class that inherits from this class (which could likely be a PhD thesis project) or use an existing class that inherits from FastFeatureDetector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There are some mistakes in your code.

  1. Replace belowe line

     ```
     std::vector<cv::Keypoint> keypoints1;
     std::vector<cv::Keypoint> keypoints2;
     ```

     with this

     ```
     std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints1;
     std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints2;
     ```
  2. For `cv::FastFeatureDetector fastDet(80);` may be you need to include library  `opencv_features2d`
- After this changes your code will run successfully.

Comment: Your welcome :).if this post solve your prblm then you can consider this post as acceptable answer.

Comment: Sorry for any trouble but what do you mean by include library opencv_features2d? Is it different from #include "opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp"

Comment: For use any library you have to link it first.So for that you need to add opencv_features2d library in your project.Otherwise you are unable to use any functions from that library even you have include header file.

Comment: After reading answer 1. sub 1 for ten times, I don't get it: you seem to suggest replacing the code with the same code... I cannot see a difference.

Comment: See this two word carefully : 1) Keypoint and KeyPoint. in second 'p' is in uppercase.

Comment: @SagarPatel it would be nice if you write the g++ compile line with the library included so that Tom Nicholas Tan understand. I would do it but I am still having problems to make it work